# Haskell Defining a Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I want to define an infinite tree in Haskell using infinitree :: Tree, but want to set a pattern up for each node, defining what each node should be. The pattern is 1 more then then its parent. I am struggling on how to set up a tree to begin with, and how and where to define the pattern of each node?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know in what ways you would like to make use of said infinite tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infinite data structures can generally be defined by functions which call themselves but have no base case. Usually these functions don't need to pattern match on their arguments. For example, a list equal to `[1..]` can be written as

```
infiniteList :: [Int]
infiniteList = go 1 where 
  go n = n : go (n+1)
```

You can use the exact same technique for a tree:

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Nil deriving (Show)

infiniteTree :: Tree Int 
infiniteTree = go 1 where 
  go n = Node (go (2*n)) n (go (2*n+1))
```

This defines the infinite tree

```
   1 
 /   \
 2   3 
/ \ / \
4 5 6 7
...
```

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot more sense no. So if I wanted a tree for the root to be 0 and it's children to be a value one more then it's parent I can do something like this:  data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Nil deriving (Foldable, Show)

infiniteTree :: Tree Int 
infiniteTree = go 0 where 
  go n = Node (go (1+n)) n (go (1+n))?

Comment: If you want that, you should instead write `go n = let a = go (1+n) in Node a n a`, because you don't want the `go (n+1)` call to be computed twice.

Comment: OTOH, they very often *do* pattern match on their arguments.

Answer (score 2):

A type for infinite binary trees with no leaves:

```
data Tree a = Tree (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

One general pattern for doing this sort of thing is called `unfold`. For this particular type:

```
unfold :: (a -> (a,b,a)) -> a -> Tree b
```

Can you see how to define this function and use it for your purpose?

Comment: data Tree = Empty | Node Integer Tree Tree deriving Show                         
infinitree :: Tree 
infinitree = go 1 where
 go n = let a = go (1+n) in Node a n a                                                         Something like this?

Comment: @YangMi, I don't know what you mean. I'm suggesting that it would be a good exercise to come up with a definition for the `unfold` function I gave you a type signature for.